# Woocommerce - Shortcode not showing on frontend

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

I’m working on this page below, and I’ve added in the shortcode using the elementor shortcode widget.

https://wordpress-878949-3053856.cloudwaysapps.com/christmas-cookies/

I’ve checked the category is correctly named and pulled the shortcode straight from Woocommerce.

The frontend just doesn’t want to meet the backend and have a nice friendly handshake and show the products.

This is the shortcode: [products limit="8" columns="4" category="christmas" cat_operator="IN”]

I have also tried:

[products limit="8" columns="4" category="christmas"]

I’ve turned off Woolentor plugin to test if that was conflicting and it wasn’t.

I’m wondering if the site is missing some PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes are working fine and your products are rendering very well but your page has inline css which is hiding the WooCommerce products container.

This is the inline CSS which is hiding the things. You can inspect elements and toggle the Elementor section and child divs and investigate this inline CSS.

```
.woocommerce ul.products {
    display: none;
}
```

Maybe Elementor is adding the inline CSS or you might have added this CSS or any other plugin is adding that, You'll have to find that and apply the possible solution to avoid or override that CSS to display your products.